# JavaFX Webview doesn't handle Javascript preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, webview, javafx, preventdefault

I've a problem with the JavaFX Webview and Javascript. Within the Webview I try to load some html content dynamicaly into a div when the User clicks a button with an `a href`. Every time I do this within the Webview, it loads the refering page directly, without loading it into the div.

In Firefox, Chrome and with Apache Server it's working properly, so it's loaded into the div container.

Here's the code to load the various content:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{   
    $(".panel-body a").click(function stopDefault(event)
    {   if (event && event.preventDefault) {
            event.preventDefault();
        var pageToLoad = $(this).attr("href");
        $("#content").load(pageToLoad);
        } else if (window.event && window.event.returnValue) 
        { window.event.returnValue = false;
        }
     });
});
```

The script is with the `if else` already prepared for standard conform browsers and IE.

I also tried it (in the beginning) with `return false;` but this was also not working. So, the default action is not prevented / disabled. And I don't have any more idea why this is just not working in JavaFX Webview.

Thanks in advice!